# Positioning FontAwesome icons in CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `h1` with 2 FontAwesome quote icons inside. I decided to control their position with CSS as I didn't find any practical way. The problem is with different screen sizes I have to use media queries and I think there is a more automated way to do this.

```
.fa-quote-left {
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    top: 15px;
    color: #34a7c1;
}
.fa-quote-right {
    position: relative;
    right: -95px;
    top: -17px;
    color: #34a7c1;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjrrfma5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it is better to work with `text-indent` and padding for the quotes, and use `<i>` instead of `<span>` ;) 
Check this out

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwn2cszo/#fork)

EDIT:

Okay, Hope this will work for you 
[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwn2cszo/6/)

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.quote {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 40px 0 50px;
}
.quote .fa-quote-left, .quote .fa-quote-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: #34a7c1;    
}
.quote .fa-quote-left {
    left:0px;
}
.quote .fa-quote-right {
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="quote"> <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-flip-vertical"></i> Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum  <br> and quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..<i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i> </h1>
```

Comment: i would like the quotes to be aligned in the middle of the two sentences!

Comment: Check updated answer :) , 
The `margin-top` depends on your `font-size`

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to explicitly set the position of the quote icon elements, you can just use the `pull-left` and `pull-right` helper classes to float them. Try this:

```
<h1> 
    <span class="fa fa-quote-left fa-flip-vertical pull-left"></span> 
    Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum<br /> 
    and quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..
    <span class="fa fa-quote-right pull-right"></span> 
</h1>
```

```css
.fa-quote-left,
.fa-quote-right {
    color: #34a7c1;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yjrrfma5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

[Referred Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjrrfma5/4/)

Just used the

```
h1{position: relative}

.fa-quote-left {
   position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: -10px;
    color: #34a7c1;
}

 .fa-quote-right {
          position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    color: #34a7c1;
    padding-right: 51px;}
```

Comment: yes but the are not equally align...they are a little bit crooked

Comment: Just check it out made some adjustments